# Deserialize object with struct declared in external library

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net

I have an object I want to deserialize, which is declared as struct in an external library (which is marked as Serializable).However, Json.net is not able to deserialize this object. Serialization is fine, but deserialize doesn't work. I already tried to change struct to class but it didn't help. Do I need to put something special in the JsonSerializerSettings or something else, or isn't it supported? I already tried several of the parameters there, like TypeNameHandling and TypeNameAssemblyFormat, but it didn't work.

As asked, some code, this is declared in external library:

```
[Serializable]
public struct BarEntry
{
    public RegistryValueKind One;
    public string Two;  
    public string Three;
    public string Four;
    public object Five;
}

[Serializable]
public struct FooEntry
{
    public string One;
    public string Two;
}
```

Serialized in own project as:

```
Stream stream = System.IO.File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Create);
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(entry, Formatting.None, new   JsonSerializerSettings { PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects });
StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(stream);
streamWriter.Write(json);
streamWriter.Flush();
stream.Close();
```

Deserialized in own project as:

```
StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(input);
string json = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
object returnObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json);
input.Close();
return returnObject;
```

Everything inside own project works fine with this code, but from external library it is not able to deserialize the objects (From both BarEntry and FooEntry).

Also BarEntry and FooEntry are both stored in the same property in their storage object:

```
public object Entry { get; set; }
```

Comment: Added, please check editted start post ;)

Comment: And when you say "doesn't work" what actually happens?

Comment: "doesn't work" = object is null.

Answer (score 0):

You must send exact type to JsonConvert.DeserializeObject, otherwise there is no way to create right object that will have needed properties to deserialize to from json string. So load this type from external assembly and send it to Json.NET. Something like this :

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFile("ExternalAssembly.dll");
Type barEntryType = assembly.GetType("BarEntry");
var returnObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json, barEntryType);
```

or reference the external assembly and simply do this :

```
BarEntry returnObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BarEntry>(json)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I already tried this but this doesn't work (see startpost, I did this exactly).

Comment: well you have object returnObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json);, it's not clear how T is defined

Comment: 'T' is a generic type, same as your 'BarEntry'.

Comment: If I dont know what type I'm going to deserialize it into, but for all I know, that type is present in the ExternalAssembly.dll. How to I proceed to deserialize into the right type now?

Comment: you have to get type from that assembly and then use JsonConvert.DeserializeObject https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_DeserializeObject_2.htm